# Executable created from python script only fires up a DOS window

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I would like to convert a python script called DEEPEM_GANTT.py to an executable file.
I read a couple of tutorials online and decided to use **pyinstaller** to complete this operation.

I went ahead and installed pywin32 and pyinstaller using pip into my Python virtual environment:

```
pip install pywin32
pip install pyinstaller
```

My first attempt at converting my script (`pyinstaller --onefile DEEPEM_GANTT.py`) returned an error (`FFi' object has no attribute 'unpack'`) but after updating cffi I was able to generate a .exe file called DEEPEM_GANTT.exe.

Alas, when double-clicking on this file it fires up a DOS window instead of lauching the tkinter dialog box that it was meant to open. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

---

My script is reproduced below. The script is designed to create a Gantt chart from data acquired using multiple sensors. The script works well when launched from a Python terminal:

```
import scipy.io
import os 
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.offline import plot
from struct import *
import datetime
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *



root = Tk()
filename = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select the folder where your sites are stored")
root.destroy()

myroot=filename



df=[]

for folder in os.listdir(myroot):
    if os.path.isdir(myroot+'/'+folder):
        for subfolder in os.listdir(myroot+'/'+folder):
            if os.path.isdir(myroot+'/'+folder+'/'+subfolder) and subfolder[:4]=='meas':
                starttime_string=subfolder[5:]
                starttime=datetime.datetime.strptime(starttime_string, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")

                for atsfilename in os.listdir(myroot+'/'+folder+'/'+subfolder):
                    if atsfilename[-3:]=='ats':
                        file_stats=os.stat(myroot+'/'+folder+'/'+subfolder+'/'+atsfilename)
                        if file_stats.st_size>0:
                            file=open(myroot+'/'+folder+'/'+subfolder+'/'+atsfilename,'rb')
                            file.seek(4)
                            byte=file.read(4)
                            nos=unpack('i', byte)[0]
                            file.seek(8)
                            byte2=file.read(4)
                            sampling=unpack('f',byte2)[0]
                            duration=nos/sampling
                            stoptime=starttime+datetime.timedelta(seconds=duration)  
                            adu=atsfilename[:3]
                
                df.append(dict(Task=folder+'_'+adu, Start=str(starttime), Finish=str(stoptime), Resource=str(sampling)))



fig = ff.create_gantt(df, index_col='Resource', show_colorbar=True, group_tasks=True)
plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic pyinstaller code to make a windowed GUI.

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w DEEPEM_GANTT.py
```

The `-w` asks it to be windowed. Also the flags `--windowed` or `--noconsole` can be used too.

Check [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Cool Cloud. Using `-w` does the trick! The executable now opens the Tkinter dialog window, so your answer hits the spot. I am still running into a `Fatal Error` later on, but that's another story...

Comment: @Sheldon Glad to know, feel free to ask a new Q about new errors.